# fread of binary file returning negative value

Tags: c

I am setting up 3 pointers to same file, each will work at a different offset. I need to read 1 byte at a time from each of them. But the fread of second pointer always showing a negative value.

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned int y; 
    unsigned int u; 
    unsigned int v; 
    FILE *yPtr;
    FILE *uPtr;
    FILE *vPtr;
    yPtr = fopen ( "test.bin", "rb"); 
    uPtr = fopen ( "test.bin", "rb"); 
    vPtr = fopen ( "test.bin", "rb"); 
    fread(&y,1,1,yPtr);
    fread(&u,1,1,uPtr); 
    fread(&v,1,1,vPtr);

    printf("%x ", y);
    printf("%x ", u);
    printf("%x ", v);

}
```

I expect: "9f 9f 9f"
But output is : "9f ffffcc9f 9f"

Comment: Does it still happen if you set y, u and v to 0 at the start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
unsigned int y; /* unintialized, default contains garbage data due to automatic storage */
```

In a 32-bit system, four bytes of memory are reserved for `y`. It looks like

```
 0x100   0x101    0x102   0x103      let's assume base address of y is 0x100
-----------------------------------
|   G   |   G     |  G     |   G  |  G- garbage
-----------------------------------
y
LSb-->
```

And here

```
fread(&y,1,1,yPtr);
```

`fread()` is reading only `1` byte from `yPtr` and storing into `y`. Now it looks like

```
0x100               0x101    0x102   0x103  
--------------------------------------------
|   valid value   |   G     |  G     |   G  |  G- garbage
--------------------------------------------
y
```

So except first bytes, remaining bytes contains still some intermediate values.

Correct is

```
fread(&y, 4, 1, yPtr); /* read 4 bytes */
```

Or **initialize** the variable first. For example,

```
unsigned int y = 0; /* now if only first byte overwritten, remaining byte contents will be zero */
```

Or if your application's intention is to read only `1` byte then use `unsigned char` type instead of `unsigned long` type. For e.g

```
unsigned char y = 0;
```

Same applicable for other variable `u` and `v` & respective `fread()` statements. Also do check the return values of library function `fopen()` and `fread()`.

Comment: There seems to be an assumption here that the machine is little-endian.  That's fairly likely to hold, but by no means guaranteed.  Overall, though, good answer.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Just learning C and learnt something new today!

Comment: yes @JohnBollinger Agree about little endian assumption.

Answer (score 4):

`unsigned`s are usually 4-8 bytes. You're reading just 1 byte into them, leaving the rest indeterminate.

If you want to read just one byte, you should read it into an `unsigned char`.

If you want to keep using `unsigned int`s, you could pre-zero them, and then you'd get the result you want provided you're on a two's complement machine.

In real code, you should also be checking your return values (at least for `fopen` and `fread`).

Comment: Thanks! Changing to unsigned char resolved the issue. Will update code to check return value too!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code.
It seems you're writing a 1-byte value in a value larger than that (depending on the CPU) which is not initialized.
An unsigned char is 1 byte, so you shouldn't have any problems:

```
int main(void) {
    unsigned char y = 0, u = 0, v = 0; 

    FILE *yPtr, *uPtr, *vPtr;
    yPtr = fopen ("test.bin","rb"); 
    uPtr = fopen ("test.bin","rb"); 
    vPtr = fopen ("test.bin","rb"); 

    fread(&y,1,1,yPtr);
    fread(&u,1,1,uPtr); 
    fread(&v,1,1,vPtr);

    printf("%x %x %x", y, u, v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change unsigned int into a unsigned char or uint8_t,byte etc...

Comment: unsigned int is 2-byte in 16-bit compiler, 4-byte on 32-bit, 8-byte on 64-bit.